# Not appearing in lauch configuration - Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

When I go `File -> Export -> Runnable JAR file`, the launch configuration is blank, no options to choose.
I got a main file... I've placed the public void main stuff... It's still not appearing.

[image: http://puu.sh/1XsuZ (pic)]

Comment: what is not appearing? post some code

Comment: Sorry, I don't want to post the code over here.
http://puu.sh/1XsUY (check that pic)

Comment: I still dont know what is your problem. You cannot run your project in Eclipse or you cannot create a runnable JAR?

Answer (score 1):

A `main` file alone isn't enough to create a "[Java Launch configuration](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_What_is_a_launch_configuration?)".

You need to at least run it once "`Run >Run As >Java Application`", as explained in "[Creating a Java application launch configuration](http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/tasks/tasks-java-local-configuration.htm) ".

*Then*, the "Runnable JAR file" dialog should include a non-empty "Java Launch configuration" for you to choose from.